# Trying to prove a trigonometric identity

Tags: trigonometry

I've been trying to solve it for quite some time but I still don't get it why it is true.

The original equation is:
\begin{equation*}
1-\frac{\sin{^2}\theta}{1-\cos\theta}=-\cos\theta.
\end{equation*}
My work so far:
\begin{equation*}
\frac{1-\cos\theta}{1-\cos\theta}-\frac{\sin{^2}\theta}{1-\cos\theta}
=\frac{1-\cos\theta-\sin{^2}\theta}{1-\cos\theta}
=\frac{(1-\sin{^2}\theta)-\cos\theta}{1-\cos\theta} \\
=\frac{\cos{^2}\theta-\cos\theta}{1-\cos\theta}
=\frac{\cos\theta(\cos\theta-1)}{1-\cos\theta}.
\end{equation*}
I saw on some sites that this is equal to $-\cos\theta$ but I don't see why.

Comment: You've got $\cos(\theta)-1$ in the numerator which is $-1\cdot(1-\cos(\theta))$.  Now cancel and you're done.

Comment: $\cos x-1=-(1-cos x)$

Answer (score 7, accepted):

$\textbf{hint}$
$$
\cos\theta -1 = -(1-\cos\theta)
$$

Comment: Got it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You're very close.
From where you left off

$\frac{\cos\theta(\cos\theta-1)}{1-\cos\theta}$

=$\frac{\cos\theta(-1)(1-\cos\theta)}{1-\cos\theta}$

=${\cos\theta(-1)}$

=${-\cos\theta}$

Comment: Some equals signs would be nice.

Answer (score 0):

Shorter:
$$1-\frac{\sin{^2}\theta}{1-\cos\theta}=-\cos\theta\iff 1+\cos\theta=\frac{\sin{^2}\theta}{1-\cos\theta}\iff 1-\cos^2\theta=\sin^2\theta.$$